# Why is my Stripe Session PaymentIntentId blank?

Tags: .net-core, stripe-payments, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to stripe and using it to test in a web api .net core 6 project. I can Create Stripe Session Service, but the PaymentIntentId is always null. I believe you need to have the PaymentIntentId when you are trying to do a refund.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

[image: Here is the complete code of the method]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version [2022-08-01](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01)

```
A PaymentIntent is no longer created during Checkout Session creation in payment mode. 
Instead, a PaymentIntent will be created when the Session is confirmed.
```

You could either store the Checkout Session id and when you want to refund get the PaymentIntent id by [retrieving](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) the Checkout Session, or you could listen to the `checkout.session.completed` event and then store the PaymentIntent Id. You can read more about the latter [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders).

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot. I also tried going back a few versions (version 39.124.0) and the payment Intent is filled out. Thanks again tarzan.

Comment: I'm glad that works for you.